# Why does my name show as [Invalid UTF-8]?

Tags: unity, users

I just did an upgrade (from 10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10) and am trying to get everything figured out.

I notice that when I log in, my name is [Invalid UTF-8].  Where is this coming from, and how can I fix it?

Update:  I tried creating a new user under 11.10, but logging in as that user showed the same problem, so it's probably not related to the upgrade.

Comment: You are affected by this bug report: please subscribe to this to receive updates.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/834137

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/834137) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 3):

try to update the UID_MIN in /etc/login.defs

```
UID_MIN                  500
```

See also here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/834137/comments/20

Comment: I don't want to have to re-create my user.

Answer (score 0):

> > try to update the UID_MIN in /etc/login.defs
> >
> > ```
> > UID_MIN                  500
> > ```

I tried the login.defs-workaround, but it does not work for me. And my user account already was UID 1000!

Perhaps this could be interesting. I updated two systems from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10: at the day of release I updated a 64-bit installation and one week later a 32-bit installation with a very similar configuration and very similar set of installed packages. Only the 64-bit installation does show this "[Invalid UTF-8]" bug. Both users (on both systems) has UID 1000!

Comment: I'm running 32 bit.