# Edit user Real name and change avatar

Tags: username, user-management

I reinstalled Ubuntu and I am now unable to change/input my Real Name. Memenu does not display usernam either. Is there a way to input this data manually by changing some hidden file or smth?!
BTW, user-manager window brakes when trying to change avatar...
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112783/invalid-utf-8-as-username) to solve your weird name issue.

Answer (score 1):

Click the *Unlock* button on the top right of the window. You can then edit the particulars of your account.

[image]

Comment: Well, I found out this is a bug, (http://askubuntu.com/questions/67745/why-does-my-name-show-as-invalid-utf-8). So it should be closed ass off-topic :)