# Where is the "About me" dialog?

Tags: 12.04, password

Looking for how to change my password the GUI way I cannot find the "About me" dialog in Ubuntu Precise (12.04) anymore. There is the "user accounts" dialog but you cannot change your own password without being root.

There is also the older "users and groups" that allows you to change your password, but the "About me" dialog was more user friendly.

Comment: very strange - as a standard user account - the "user accounts" dialog allows me to change my own password without being root.

Comment: Related? - [Edit user real name and change avatar](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118846/edit-user-real-name-and-change-avatar/118857#118857)

Answer (score 1):

In `user accounts` you have to **click onto the dots** of your password to change it:

[image: change pw]